# Naming convention for fractional linear transformations

Tags: terminology

According to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation), Möbius transformations are known by many different names, including:

homographies, homographic transformations, linear fractional transformations, bilinear transformations, and fractional linear transformations.

Is there a preferred name which is most commonly used?

Comment: "M\"obius", "homographic" and "fractional linear" are all used very often. I would certainly not call myself these transformations "bilinear" (I haven't even understood the question was about M\"obius transformations before opening it).

Comment: In my experience, "Möbius" and "fractional linear" are the most commonly used names.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. "Möbius" and "fractional linear" are in both collections, so looks like they may be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

To not leave the question without an answer: it transpired in comments that "Möbius transformation" and "fractional linear transformation" are the most commonly used terms.